# Posted data variables not being saved by PHP script

Tags: php, variables, post

I'm a (junior) pen tester and I'm trying to make a script to demonstrate the dangers of an XSS attack to a client. I've got a php script that is meant to log user:pass combos when victims (i.e. myself in the demo) are redirected to a malicious page I'm hosting.

This is the part of the source for the login:

```
<input  type="text" id="form_login_username" name="form[login][username]" value=""       class="large" />
<input  type="password" id="form_login_password" name="form[login][password]" value="" class="large" />
```

I'm new to php so it might be something really basic that's cause the problem. Here is my php script to log the details:

```
<?PHP
$filename = "login_details.txt";
$username = $_POST["form[login][username]"]; 
$password = $_POST["form[login][password]"];
$fh = fopen($filename, "aw") or die("cannot open file");
fwrite($fh, $username . ":" . $password . "\r\n");
fclose($fh);
```

With this script I get:

```
 Notice: Undefined index: form[login][username] in...
```

And the same for the password.

I added in     isset to see if the variables are even being set, and they're not.

I know the script does work, as I tried it with a few other simple login pages and it's worked perfectly. The only difference is that the username and password post variables in this case have square brackets in them - could this be the issue? I have tried url encoding them but to no avail :(

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Thank you =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the valid way to access your variables is

```
$_POST['form']['login']['username']
```

Just perform `var_dump($_POST);` and see what your post contains

Comment: bingo! I knew it was something silly =) - thanks a lot zerkms!

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, in your form name attributes...

```
name="formUsername"
name="formPasswd"
```

In your receiving script...

```
$username = $_POST['formUsername']; 
$password = $_POST['formPasswd];
```

Comment: You can still set form elements to array values, it can sometimes  help to cluster them

Comment: thanks for your help, but I went with the other answer - cheers though =)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `<form action="youscript.php" method="post">` around that fields?